# Can you export configuration of resources in Azure using Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell

I need to export configuration like what IP Whitelisting is applied to resources in Azure to CSV.

Is it possible to do this with Powershell?

Comment: Different resource types restrict access differently, could you describe what you're looking to do in more detail? A SQL database has firewall settings, where an App Service could have IP restrictions, or VNet integration in place.

Comment: I just want a list of all relevant configurations for a resource. So run that against the resource group and it exports all configuration settings into a CSV. Used to be able to do this sort of stuff with WMI years ago :)

Comment: Why are you re-asking the question you asked three hours previously? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66545880/export-azure-configuration-posh

Comment: Deleted the other post. Mixup on that apols

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export the ARM template for a resource group from the Azure CLI or Powershell.

[CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/manage-resource-groups-cli#export-resource-groups-to-templates):
`az group export --name $resourceGroupName`

[Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/manage-resource-groups-powershell#export-resource-groups-to-templates):
`Export-AzResourceGroup -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName`

A few resources will have restrictions on exporting templates, but templates usually have all the settings.